How to change the description of a GEE asset from the API?
I created an ImageCollection. It updated by a pipeline on regular basis so everything related to the asset lives in the pipeline repo including the description in a README.md. I want it to become the single source of thruth so every time the pipeline runs it first check that the description didn't change.
an image collection would be ee.ImageCollection("<assetID>") but I didn't fid anything to change the description.
Is there a way to do it from the API ?

Thanks to this SO post, I found a undocumented method that does exactly what I need:
ee.data.setAssetProperties("users/pierrickrambaud/test1", {"description": "toto"})

It exist in the source code
I opened an issue on GEE tracker to have it exposed in the API reference.
